# jQuery - Find Closest element and replace text

Tags: jquery

I have list of employees with `more` link at the top section.

If I click on more link, I want get the value of relevant element and display at the bottom...

> **[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ertbrm5g/)**

Please have a look at the code below and guide me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var empName = $(this).closest('.emp-details').find('.ename').text();
  var empDesignation = $(this).closest('.emp-details').find('.edesignation').text();
  $('.more-info').on('click', function(){
    $('#info-container').show();
    $('#info-container #empname').text(empName);
    $('#info-container #designation').text(empDesignation);
  });

});
```

Comment: Set your variables **inside** click handler...

Comment: You are running `closest()` against the `document`, which is the top level, so it will never find any `.emp-details`. did you mean to put these two lines in the click handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the value of `empName` and `empDesignation` each time you click on the `more info` button. Which means, you need to set those variables inside `more-info` click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.more-info').on('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.emp-details')
    var empName = parent.find('.ename').text();
    var empDesignation = parent.find('.edesignation').text();
    $('#info-container').show();
    $('#empname').text(empName);
    $('#designation').text(empDesignation);
  })
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ertbrm5g/1/)